# Hide some tags for non-admin users

Tags: permissions, tags

We are using CiviCRM to manage different kinds of contacts. Therefore we have some tags that are irrelevant to the "regular", non-admin users (e.g. "check membership fees" for a user who doesn't even have permission to view member contacts)

The tag list starts to become long and cluttered. Can I hide some tags (and their child tags) for some users?

Maybe something similar to hiding/showing a "set of custom data fields" using ACLs?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect solution, but to help declutter you could create an "Admin tags" tagset and make all the admin tags children of that one. They'd still be available to the non-admins but wouldn't be in the regular list of tags -- they show up as an autocomplete field underneath:

[image: Tags]